# Zooming part of QGraphicsItem with its child items

Tags: zooming

I'm new to Qt and stuck with an issue. I've a QGraphicsPixmap item with few child items(rectangles and ellipses) in it which subsequently have some child items. Now I want to show a part of Graphicspixmap item with all the child items zooming in a QLabel on mousehover event. 
So what I've done is as follows;

```
GraphicsPixmapItem::GraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap pixmap):QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
{
setAcceptsHoverEvents(true);
}

void GraphicsPixmapItem::hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
QPointF p = event->pos();
QRect rect(p.x(), p.y(), 100, 100);
lb->setPixmap(pixmap().copy(rect).scaled(lb->width(),lb->height()));
lb->repaint();
QApplication::processEvents();
}

void GraphicsPixmapItem::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
lb=new QLabel();
lb->resize(400,400);
lb->show();
}

void GraphicsPixmapItem::hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
lb->close();
}
```

This is zooming Graphicspixmap perfectly but not the child items. My question is how to show Graphicspixmap with its child items in the QLabel and is there any better approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found my solution by my own and thought of sharing that, so that anyone facing the same problem can save their time on this issue. 
I've done it in two ways. First I've solved it using mousehover event on the same line as was working before, which is as follows:

```
void GraphicsPixmapItem::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
imageviewLabel=new QLabel();
imageviewLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
imageviewLabel->setGeometry(QApplication::desktop()->width()/2, 50, 600, 600);
imageviewLabel->show();
}

void GraphicsPixmapItem::hoverMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
QRect viewrect(event->pos().x(), event->pos().y(), 100, 100);
imageviewLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::grabWidget(QApplication::mainWidget(),viewrect).scaled(imageviewLabel->width(),imageviewLabel->height()));
imageviewLabel->repaint();
QApplication::processEvents();
}

void GraphicsPixmapItem::hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event)
{
imageviewLabel->close();
}
```

To make this code working for you, just have to make your main window a main widget which I've set with the flag :
QApplication::setMainWidget(this); //within Mainwindow constructor

Then I found a better solution of my problem which decrease the line of code and complexity significantly. This is by implementing wheelMove event:

```
void GraphicsPixmapItem::wheelEvent(QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent *event)
{
prepareGeometryChange();
setScale(scale()*exp(-event->delta() / 600.0));
}
```

I hope this would help at least some of you. Enjoy!